# Integration Question on $\int \frac{1}{x^2+10x+21} \, dx$

Tags: integration

How would i do the following indefinite integration $$\int \frac{1}{x^2+10x+21} \, dx$$

so far I've turned the bottom polynomial into $(x+7)(x+3)$ not too sure where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Partial Fractions:
$$\frac{1}{(x+7)(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x+7}+\frac{B}{x+3}$$
Now find $A,B$ and use the linearity of the integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{(x+7)(x+3)} dx=\int \frac{A}{x+7}dx+\int \frac{B}{x+3}dx$$
This should be simple now.

EDIT: Evaluating $A,B$:
$$\frac{1}{(x+7)(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x+7}+\frac{B}{x+3}\iff 1=A(x+3)+B(x+7)$$
Setting $x=-3$ and $x=-7$ give $A,B=?$

Comment: oh dear i cant believe i didnt think of this!! thankyou :)

Comment: urmm one quick question from the above partial integrals how would i work out the values of A and B?

Comment: i understand the answer would be $Alog(x+7) + Blog(x+3)$ but dont really know how to work out A and B

Comment: $A= -1/4$ and $B=1/4$ thankyou :D

Comment: @jill Exactly!!